# Textarea not sliding up when keyboard appears in Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, css

We have created a mobile view page on my website which show a text-area towards the bottom of page. In most of the mobile-devices/browser, the page work fines and the text-area is slides up when keyboards comes up.

But, in HTC One V (Android 4.0.3) default browser the text-area does not shift up and hence is hidden behind the keyboard, so user can't see what he is typing. Though on same device using chrome it is working fine.

Please note that this works correctly in default browser in android 4.1.2 (Galaxy S3)

Any help to solve this issue would be appreciated.

EDIT:
This is mobile view for a website not an android app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your [Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Answer (score 0):

You should add`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in Manifest file which will resize the window or adjust the window accordingly.

For xml solution: **Visit my** [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634323/still-my-layout-not-shifting-up-side/18635477#18635477)

Comment: The problem is happening on my web page. It is not an android app.